# Why does the Python shell output something even when there is no "print" command?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I wrote the following code in Python IDLE, using its editor

```py
import urllib.request
print(urllib.request.urlopen('https://github.com').read().decode('utf-8'))
```

and then saved the code as a script. After I ran the script, Python displayed the page source I want.

When I changed the above code to:

```py
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('https://github.com').read().decode('utf-8')
```

and then ran the script, Python displayed nothing. This is understandable.

The weird thing for me, however, is that if I run the above code (the one without `print`) **interactively** in a Python shell, Python shell can still display the page source, as you see:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request.urlopen('https://github.com').read().decode('utf-8')
'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html\n  lang="en"\n  \n  \n ...'
```

(output snipped)

I don't understand why.

Comment: Any statements in the interactive Python shell that returns a value but not assigned to a variable has its `repr` (representation form) printed onto the console.  If that was assigned to a variable (i.e. `contents = urllib....`) no output will be dumped.

Comment: the python shell will by default print the result of the commands that you run

Comment: This is just what the shell does, as a special case for running interactively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the interactive python prompt. It automatically prints return values for you so that you can see the result of what you're doing.

Try typing `3 + 2`. You know this doesn't print anything either - but you will see the result.

Likewise, if you put those two lines into a file you won't get any output.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the shell is printing the result of execution. If you assign the function call to a variable then it will suppress the printing.

i.e. `html = urllib.request.urlopen( ... )`